# How to make a counter for each array elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm new in JS and i need your help with some code.

Ok, here's the thing. I'm trying to make a counter for each element of the "names" array.

Here's the code:

```
    var bool = [false, false, false];

    var names = ["Banana", "Apple", "Pear"];
    var prices = [10, 20, 30]
    var sell = ["not purchased!", "not purchased!", "not purchased!"];  
    var text;
    var count = 0;
    function checkbuy (names) {
    while (text != 0)
    {
      text = prompt("product list: " + names)
      names.sort((a, b) => { return (text.includes(b)) - (text.includes(a)); });

      if (names.indexOf(text) >= 0)
      {
        bool[names.indexOf(text)] = true;
        sell[names.indexOf(text)] = "purchased!";
        count[names.indexOf(text)]  += 1;
        alert("Product " + text.toUpperCase() + " is purchased!");
      }
      for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
      {
        var myList = [ [names[i], prices[i], bool[i], sell[i], count], [names[i], prices[i], bool[i], sell[i], count], [names[i], prices[i], bool[i], sell[i], count ] ];

        // alert(myList[i][0]);
        alert(names[i] + " " + sell[i] + ", " + bool[i] + count)

      }
      alert(names);
    }
}
```

I need to enter a value in the prompt, and if it matches the value from the array, then I need to add that item to the list. The addition must occur by using a counter. For example, I enter a value "Banana" in the "prompt field" and the counter value should increase by one. And I need to do so for each element in the array. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain two arrays, one for list of items and one for their corresponding counter.

For each prompt item, if it matches an item in `names`, you can increment the corresponding index in `sold`. Now, in your sold array, anything `== 0` is `not purchased`, and you don't need another array to track that.

```js
var names = ["Banana", "Apple", "Pear"];
var sold = [0, 0, 0];

let exitPrompt = true;

while (exitPrompt) {
  let promptVal = prompt('what do you want to buy?');
  if (promptVal && promptVal.indexOf('exit') == 0) {
    console.log(sold);
    break;
  } else {
    let nameIndex = names.indexOf(promptVal);
    if (nameIndex >= 0) {
      sold[nameIndex] += 1;
    }
  }
}
```